# Why does the second loop execute before the first loop?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

so this might be a repost, but I don't really know how to explain my second problem.
I have this code:

```
var paragraphsArray = new Array();
function setParagraphs(offSet) 
{
    offSet = offSet * 12;
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) 
    {
        var parX = i + offSet;
        var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php', {idd: parX}).done(function(paragraph) 
        {
            //clear paragraph1 div 
            document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = "";
            //create p elements
            var pElem = document.createElement("p");
            pElem.setAttribute("id", "pEntry"+i);
            document.getElementById("paragraph1").appendChild(pElem);
            $("pEntry"+i).text(paragraph);
        });
    }
}
```

edited: I removed the second loop because it was unnecessary, for some reason the p element creation starts on `i==13`, which is the extra one that shouldn't even do.

for some reason the second loop executes first, so the paragraphArray is printed out as `undefined`. I managed to "fix" the order with the `setTimeout()` function, BUT I still get the undefined message, instead of the value. In the first loop the value is printed out fine, but if I try and put it in a `$("p").text(paragraph);` I also get undefined. So although I was right about the execution order, the problem is still there!

Comment: This is because the first loop is sending out page requests, which are being run in parallel and take longer to complete than the rest of the Javascript. Once the `$.get` is called, the next line of Javascript code is executed as `$.get` goes out and retrieves the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because first is in `ajax` call, declare `paragraphsArray` in `global` space and use a callback function, try this:

***Updated**

```
var paragraphsArray = [];
function setParagraphs(offSet) {
    offSet = offSet * 12;
    var request = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        var parX = i + offSet;
        var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php', {idd: parX}).done(function(paragraph) {
            request++;
            paragraphsArray[request] = paragraph;
            console.log(paragraphsArray[request]);
            if (request === 12) {
                alert('first');
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
}
function callback() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);
    }
    alert('second');
}
```

Comment: for some reason, even though it i reaches 12 the callback function is not runned/called, is it because of the triple =??

Comment: even if it runs, for some reason the second loop returns undefined as well. its like the problem with my `settimeout()` solution

Comment: works as promised with an explanation as to what caused the problem

Comment: one minor problem I face here is that because (am guessing) of the delay in $.get() paragraphsArray[x] might not be the 4th item in the database but the 1st or 8th or any. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: return the `id` and `paragraph` as `object data` from server, something like `paragraphsArray[data.id] = data.paragraph;`

Comment: just to be sure, in the php side it would be something like class `User{public $uid; public $uPara;}` and i would `echo user($id,$para)` and in javascript i would still put it in paragraphsArray and say `paragraph.id` and `paragraph.para`??

Comment: Replace `var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php', {idd: parX}).done(function(paragraph) {` with `var testASd = $.getJSON('php/entryParagraphs.php', {idd: parX}).done(function(data) {` and in php side you have to do someting like `header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('id' => 1, 'paragraph' => 'some text'));`

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is async function. 1st cycle will just send requests and wouldn't wait for response, so 2nd cycle will start right after first, without getting response of `$.get` function. Thats why `console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);` in 2nd cycle shows undefined.

You only can handle response in first cylce.

You can use `$("p").text(paragraph);` only like in this example:

```
var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php',  { idd: parX }).done(function(paragraph) {
    paragraphsArray[i] = paragraph;

    console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);
    alert('first');

    $("p").text(paragraph);
});
```

You can't use variables, which are assigned in function

```
function(paragraph) {
    paragraphsArray[i] = paragraph;

    console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);
    alert('first');

    $("p").text(paragraph);
}
```

outside of this function.

To achieve what you want you have to use another approach.

HTML will be:

```
<div id='paragraphs'>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php',  { idd: parX }).done(function(paragraph) {
    $("#results").append("<p>"+paragraph+"</p>")
});
```

You should use ~ this code. I just show you approach.

Comment: I tried to use the paragraph in the first loop, because the second loop is completely unnecessary, it was a try to overcome the first problem, which is: i can print in the console, and in the alert() msg, but i cant use the value for the purpose i want to, i want to put the paragraph value in a `$("p").text(paragraph);` which didnt work, it assigned the value as undefined.

Comment: @alexandros Where exactly you tried this? You can do this in first cycle. You can't do this outside of `$.get` function.

Comment: `var paragraphsArray = new Array();
 function setParagraphs(offSet) {
     offSet = offSet * 12;
     for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
         var parX = i + offSet;
         var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php', {idd: parX}).done(function(paragraph) {
             //clear paragraph1 div 
    document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = "";
    //create p elements
    var pElem = document.createElement("p");
    pElem.setAttribute("id", "pEntry"+i);
    document.getElementById("paragraph1").appendChild(pElem);
    $("pEntry"+i).text('teest');
         });
     }
 }`

Comment: am sorry i couldnt type my code and my msg, i removed the 2nd loop completely, because its unnececary and now its like this, the problem is that it goes immidietely to i==13, and skips everything else, because it generates only one p element, with the id of pEntry13

Comment: @alexandros You just had shown us how to not use comments in so. Updated your question. It is impossible to read code now.

Comment: done,am sorry i thought comments would use a similar output to the question's format

Comment: yes thats what i did in the first place, but for some reason, the p text area is still empty, and it also creates only 1 p element, instead of 12. the second loop was a workaround with the array but that too, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Run the second loop inside of the first loop.

```
function setParagraphs (offSet) {
    //paragraphs
    var testing = 0;
    var paragraphsArray = new Array();
    offSet = offSet * 12;
    for (var i=1;i<13;i++) {
        var parX = i + offSet;
        var testASd = $.get('php/entryParagraphs.php',  { idd: parX }).done(function(paragraph) {
            paragraphsArray[i] = paragraph;
            console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);
            alert('first');
            for (var i=1;i<13;i++) {
                 console.log(paragraphsArray[i]);
                 alert('second');
             }
        });
    }
}
```